# mLab doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I've added mLab to my Heroku app, I also use mongoose. I tried use connection string from localhost, and it was working(almost). In my server file I use:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
if (process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://heroku_fb82r7lw:bbgj8uliam1psdda88fleu55li@ds161580.mlab.com:61580/heroku_fb82r7lw');

    // mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://heroku_fb82r7lw:bbgj8uliam1psdda88fleu55li@ds161580.mlab.com:61580/heroku_fb82r7lw');

    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fitMe')
}
```

If I open the app from localhost, it saves things to the db, and can get it back, although not everything, but on heroku it doesn't work at all. I use react with server. I think that something wrong with the routs.. so here is the link to server file : 
https://github.com/HelenaVolskaia/Motivation/blob/master/server/app.js

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to use the mLab add on to use mLab on Heroku: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

Comment: yes, I'm using it, the connection string from mLab

Comment: When you say "doesn't work at all," what do you mean? Does the data just *disappear*? Is there an error message? Need more details.

Comment: Request failed with status code 404, I can't post/get information.

Comment: so when you run the heroku app, is the mongodb connection failing? If your server is not able to connect to mongo labs, then the server will stop giving some error(saying not able to connect to mongodb). Are you not able to run your server, so the error is something else?

Comment: I don't think that the problem with connection to the db, I can use mLab from my localhost, but it doesn't work on heroku, I think the problem somewhere in routes, probably http/https issue, since this is the only deference I can see between running on local and on heroku.

Comment: 1. You do not have to use the mLab add on to use mLab on Heroku. A connection string is sufficient. 2. I recommend tailing your Heroku logs to see what's going on: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#real-time-tail. It sounds like the underlying issue is being abstracted from you right now. 3. Feel free to reach out to support@mlab.com if you need any help. (I work at mLab)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an env variable locally and only use this:

```
// Connect Mongo
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; // mongoose promises deprecated, use node - mongoosejs.com/docs/promises
mongoose.connect(config.db.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => { console.log('MongoDB Connected'); });
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => { console.log('MongoDB connection error: ', err); });
```

But regardless, add the on connection error handler and see what the error is, so you can dig deeper into why it's not connecting.